# For all integers $a\ge 2$, show there exist infinitely many $n$ such that $n+a$ divides $a^n+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For all integers $a\ge 2$, show there exist infinitely many $n$ such that $n+a$ divides $a^n+1$.

I just need a hint for this one. If I modify the problem to $n$ divides $a^n+1$, it's easy (using orders, FLT, etc).

Comment: You can try: $t = n + a$ and modify your expression. Then you could prove it by induction or using smth another.

Comment: The only problem is that even for $a=2$ I can't find even one value of $n$ which works, except for $n=1$.

Comment: In fact, checking with a computer, the second smallest solution for $a=2$ is $t=49737$ !